# Some kind of "encrypted" QR codes?

Tags: encryption, android, qr-code

I'm looking of some kind of solution that enables me to print some kind of "encrypted" QR codes, so scanning of it with regular QR-code reader will display non-sense, but scanning with some "special" QR-code reader in which I enter some kind of "decryption key", will display correct text.

I'm not looking to real good encryption, just some kind of "security-by-obscurity" or "just XOR" will work for me. It isn't meant to resists vs dedicated hacker, only to create some barrier.

It should be fairly easy programmed, but I rather using existing solution, preferable some form of Android Application.

Comment: That's an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) question and a recommendation question, so it's off-topic. I guess your actual problems could be solved by guys at [security.se].

Comment: Couldn't you just print a regular QR code with the _data_ inside it encrypted?

Comment: How about [this?](http://qrdroid.com/blog/encrypted-qr-codes-share-secret-messages/)

Comment: @jcbermu that's seems what I'm looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One simple-seeming answer (that I haven't tried) might be to print the QR code as a "negative" -- that is, invert the blacks and whites.  A common QR reader won't recognize it then, but all that's required to use it is to take a photo, invert it with photo editing software (provided on the phone or user installed), then feed the inverted photo to the QR reader.  For folks too young to have handled a lot of photographic negatives, this would require "out of the box" thinking to bypass.